# Background color going out of the column while using 100%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5. I have created 2 columns on my page.

**This is the output I was getting it.**

[image]

Now, I have to show an orange color from end to end of my left side column. So I have added `h-100` to my `orange` class or I can add the `height:100%` to my `orange` class.

**Now I am getting the below output**

[image]

**This is my expected output**

[image]

Any idea how to solve this?

```css
.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h2>Heading one</h2>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="testing">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h2>Heading Two</h2>
      <div class="orange h-100">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of you are using Bootstrap it is better to add `.container(your parent class)` before changing style of bootstrap classes.

use `.container .row(Bootstrap class)`
not to effect all of the Bootstrap row classes in you project

and for the second solution

`.container .col-lg-6`

---

You can get rid of `h-100`  and apply

```css
.orange {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100%;
}

.container .row{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

---

```css
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: bisque;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100%;
}

.container .row {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h2>Heading one</h2>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="testing">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h2>Heading Two</h2>
      <div class="orange ">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or you can apply

```css
.container .col-lg-6{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: bisque;
}

.container .col-lg-6 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h2>Heading one</h2>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="testing" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h2>Heading Two</h2>
      <div class="orange">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or similar to first approach but not using `overflow:hidden;`

```css
img{
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  margin:0;
  background-color: bisque;
}

.container .col-lg-6{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h2>Heading one</h2>
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="testing" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h2>Heading Two</h2>
          <div class="orange">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
              eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
              enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
              nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
              reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
              nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
              sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why are we adding the overflow hidden to the row? If I remove both heading then it's showing my expected output.

Comment: `height:100%` is your .row height which is parent classes height, if there is no heading it will work perfect but if you had another element, your divs height(child element) still be 100% but total height is [100% + your new elements height] so when you add `overflow:hidden` you will say that row container that if there is an  element which is overflowing that container, (some part of 100%) it will not show that. @user9437856

Comment: Yes, I agree with your last comment but If I use the overflow:hidden then If I add any shoadow or any border to the orange class then it will cut from the bottom.

Comment: Yes than you should use the second approach @user9437856 which u tell the .orange `flex:basis:100%` ,  go grow and use 100% of the space that there is left

Comment: Add a third approach that which is not using `overflow:hidden` only using `height:100%` @user9437856

Answer (score 0):

To avoid messing with overflow and using Bootstrap at its fullest, add `d-flex flex-column` to the right col. Flex elements have the advantage to match its siblings size.
My personal advice is to replace `h-100` with a css rule `height: 100%` and get rid of the unecessary `!important` annotation.

```css
.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h2>Heading one</h2>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="testing">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex flex-column">
      <h2>Heading Two</h2>
      <div class="orange h-full">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 display-container" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
    <div class="col-lg-6" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
      <h2>Heading one</h2>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="testing">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6" style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;">
      <h2>Heading Two</h2>
      <div class="orange h-full" style="height: 100%;background-color: orange;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I hope this is what you are expecting.. Has limited CSS as well

Comment: best to comment and explain what you did

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A Bootstrap-only solution would consist of adding the `img-fluid` class to your image so it uses `max-width: 100%;`. You have `h-100` but there is overflow, so it's best to use `d-flex` with `flex-column` on the parent in which you have your custom div, `.orange`.

```css
.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h2>Heading one</h2>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="testing" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex flex-column">
      <h2>Heading Two</h2>
      <div class="orange h-100">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```